# WPF Storyboard.Completed event is not immediate

Tags: wpf

In WPF, a `Storyboard` can be stopped by `Storyboard.SkipToFill()`, but the `Completed` event will not be fired immediately. Just as the following demo code showing:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Storyboard _storyboard = new Storyboard();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeStoryboard();
    }

    private void InitializeStoryboard()
    {
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
            From = 0,
            To = 300
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, MyRectangle);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(WidthProperty));

        _storyboard = new Storyboard();
        _storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        _storyboard.Completed += StoryboardOnCompleted;
    }

    private void StartButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _storyboard.Begin(this, true);
    }

    private void StopButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _storyboard.SkipToFill(this);
        Debug.WriteLine(@"SkipToFill");
    }

    private void StoryboardOnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"Completed");
    }
}
```

Click the `StartButton` to begin the `Storyboard`, and then click the `StopButton` to stop it. The output will be:

- SkipToFill
- Completed

So, my question: How to make the `Completed` event fired immediately? i.e. to make the output be:

- Completed
- SkipToFill

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible. Why do you need such a behavior at all?

Comment: It's a problem about design. The `Storyboard` is wrapped in a class named of `MyPlayer`, which exposes `Start` and `Stop` methods. Have invoked the `Stop` method, want to get the `MyPlayer`'s `Property` which was updated in the `Completed` event. Actually not a property, but something like that. You may say a event in `MyPlayer` is needed, but that not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control when the `Storyboard` raises the `Completed` event but you could handle the event whenever it occurs.

So you could hook up another event handler to the `Completed` event and do whatever you want in there after the `Completed` event has been raised.

This will print the output in the expected order, i.e. the event handlers will be invoked in the order you register them:

```
private void StopButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _storyboard.Completed += _storyboard_Completed;
    _storyboard.SkipToFill(this);
}

private void _storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(@"SkipToFill");
    _storyboard.Completed -= _storyboard_Completed;
}

private void StoryboardOnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(@"Completed");
}
```

If you want to actually block (asynchronously) in the `StopButton_OnClick` method until the `Completed` has been raised, you could use a `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private readonly System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
private async void StopButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _storyboard.Completed += (ss, ee) => _semaphore.Release();
    _storyboard.SkipToFill(this);
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync(); //wait here...

    Debug.WriteLine(@"SkipToFill");

}

private void StoryboardOnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(@"Completed");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `SkipToFill` method *schedules* an end of the animation. I suppose you could try to wait for the renderer to run (sort of). I doubt that it will work, but anyway:

```
_storyboard.SkipToFill(this);

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action(delegate { }), DispatcherPriority.Background);

Debug.WriteLine(@"SkipToFill");
```

Comment: Here's a good link for you downvoter: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes Anyway, this is the answer. In fact, the first sentence was found in the .NET source code.